# Inserting record in to MySQL Database using C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am currently developing an application using C# WPF. I am trying to store data into a MySQL Database. Below is the code that I have.

```
 MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("", conn);

                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BUG_REPORTS (bug_softwareID, bug_firstName, bug_lastName, bug_email, bug_description, bug_ip_addr, bug_dateReported) "
                    + "VALUES (@softwareID, @firstName, @lastName, @email, @description, @ip_addr, @dateReported)";

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@softwareID");
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstName");
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@lastName");
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@email");
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@description");
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ip_addr");
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@dateReported");

                cmd.Parameters["@softwareID"].Value = softwareID;
                cmd.Parameters["@firstName"].Value = getFirstName();
                cmd.Parameters["@lastName"].Value = getLastName();
                cmd.Parameters["@email"].Value = getEmail();
                cmd.Parameters["@description"].Value = getDescription();
                cmd.Parameters["@ip_addr"].Value = ip_addr;
                cmd.Parameters["@dateReported"].Value = date;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Everytime I try to insert a record it comes up with the error 'Only MySQLParameter objects may be stored. What am I doing wrong. I found article and everything appears to be OK.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your paramters try:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@softwareID", softwareID));
```

And so on and so forth with the rest of your parameters.

And in all honesty it might be just as simple just to build your sql inline and execute the command without parameters unless your not validating text and are concerned about injection attacks.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help.I have got it working but not quite in the way you suggested but answer did help me. I'm not using Odbc so I left out the OdbcParameter which it now came up with deprecated and suggested something different. So I used cmd.Parameters.AddWithValues("@softwareID", softwareID));

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it translates over directly, but when I want to INSERT or UPDATE a table with T-SQL I use .ExecuteScalar().

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery() is the correct method to call for INSERT or UPDATE.  ExecuteScalar() is for returning a single value (like a count) or for reading the first column of the first row that is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it using this style. It is a lot more compact and might possibly solve your problem.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@softwareID",softwareID);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstName",getFirstName());
cmd.Parameters.Add("@lastName",getLastName());
cmd.Parameters.Add("@email",getEmail());
cmd.Parameters.Add("@description",getDescription());
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ip_addr",ip_addr);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@dateReported",date);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Yea I did try that but Visual Studio said add was deprecated and to use addwithvalues instead

Answer (score 0):

The parameter identifier with the MySql .NET connector is '?'.

So you must use the following code:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO BUG_REPORTS (bug_softwareID, bug_firstName, bug_lastName, bug_email, bug_description, bug_ip_addr, bug_dateReported) "
                        + "VALUES (?softwareID, ?firstName, ?lastName, ?email, ?description, ?ip_addr, ?dateReported)";

cmd.Parameters.Add("?softwareID");
cmd.Parameters.Add("?firstName");
cmd.Parameters.Add("?lastName");
cmd.Parameters.Add("?email");
cmd.Parameters.Add("?description");
cmd.Parameters.Add("?ip_addr");
cmd.Parameters.Add("?dateReported");

cmd.Parameters["?softwareID"].Value = softwareID;
cmd.Parameters["?firstName"].Value = getFirstName();
cmd.Parameters["?lastName"].Value = getLastName();
cmd.Parameters["?email"].Value = getEmail();
cmd.Parameters["?description"].Value = getDescription();
cmd.Parameters["?ip_addr"].Value = ip_addr;
cmd.Parameters["?dateReported"].Value = date;
```