# load many txt files to mysql db

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc, mysql-workbench, workbench

I want to store 7000 records consisting of txt files as datatype BLOB in my DB using workbench.

But:

**1.** I don't know how to do it automatically? Should I put all the files in one catalogue and then write a script to take them one by one and insert in the adequate rows?

**2.** I am not sure if BLOB is fine for this type of file storage? Later I want to connect my DB with GUI so after clicking, it should be possible to open each txt file in new window.

Could you advice me how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write a script, yes. If it's hard for you to put them all in one folder I think there are scripts and tools to do this.

You can use C#, PHP or any other lang to scan those files and then insert them into the database.

Bunch of tutorials:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-files-from-directory/
[Inserting record in to MySQL Database using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021425/inserting-record-in-to-mysql-database-using-c-sharp)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/scanning-folders-with-php/
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php13p3.html

Blob should do, takes around 20 megabytes of text.